# Is it possible to Access network path in excel connection manager

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to load multiple excel to SQL. But challenge is to load the excel file from the network path.

I have saved the same file on my local system then it is working. But when I load it from network path its loading the same file which is their on my local machine.

I searched on google but there is nothing regarding the network path.

I am having full permission on that folder as well

Someone has any idea regarding this.

Comment: This is an old example but still applicable: http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx

Comment: @Red Devil what exactly the error or warning ? Is this because of UNC path ?

Comment: Have you setup any configurations for your package? This may overwrite your current variables. You can check this by going to SSIS->Package Configurations... assuming you are using 'Package Deployment' model